# how type in command adb -kill server?

Tags: android

[image]
when i type in cmd adb kill server it give me that adb not recognized. i cannot find the adb location in windows . what should i do to type in cmd to kill the adb

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    TextView textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    String[] item = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.index);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_second,R.id.txt,item);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font.ttf");
    textView.setTypeface(typeface);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
            intent.putExtra("page",i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Please clarify what your code has to do with the question, it is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Program adb.exe is inside Android SDK Folder. Here is the path:

```
\SDK\platform-tools\
```

Go there(`\SDK\platform-tools\`) ==> `SHIFT & RIGHT click`. Then `cmd` will open inside that directory so that you can run `"adb kill-server"`.

Comment: i Go inside i found adb icon  i press shift &Right click  no cmd open could u more clear?should i check adb icon before  shift&right click?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Task Manager`using `Ctrl+Shift+Esc`

then

click on `processes` find `adb.exe`

`Right-Click` on `adb.exe`

and click on `End Task`

Answer (score 0):

For stop server in windows OS : adb kill-server
For start server in windows OS : adb start-server